# Prove that sub-convex combination is a contraction

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, contraction-operator

Let $V$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{T}$ an operator acting on the vector. Let $V^*$ be the fixed point of $\mathcal{T}$ such that
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{T}V^* = V^*
\end{equation}
Assume that for $\mathcal{T}$ and any $V$, $\mathcal{T}V - V^*$ is a sub-convex combination:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{T}V_i - V^*_i = \sum_{k=1}^n w_k (V_k - V_k^*) \quad \forall i = 1, \:...\:n 
\end{equation}
where $\sum_{k=1}^n w_k= \gamma \le 1$ and $w_k \ge 0$

Can I then conclude the following?
\begin{equation}
\vert \mathcal{T}V_i - V^*_i \vert \le \gamma \vert\vert V - V^*\vert\vert
\end{equation}
where $\vert\vert . \vert\vert$ is the supremum norm, i.e. $\vert\vert v \vert\vert = \sup_k \vert v_k\vert$

Comment: I guess $w_k\geq 0$? In this case, simply apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten to write it. Am I right in saying that the conclusion directly comes from the fact that the summation $\sum_k w_k(V_k - V^*_k)$ cannot be greater than $\gamma ||V - V^*||$, i.e. when all the weight is given to the maximum difference?

Comment: But this "fact" is exactly the conclusion you want to make. And it follows, as I said, directly from the triangle inequality.